# How to run an interactive Python script as cron job?

Tags: python, linux, macos, cron

I have a Python script, say `test.py` which interacts with the user everytime it is executed.

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def foo():
    a = input()
    print("Hello, {}".format(a))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

I want to run this script every 5 minutes. So, I tried adding it to my `crontab` but it seems that this doesn't work as I am not prompted to enter an input.
 I have tested my `crontab` and it is working fine.

Should I use libraries such as `schedule` for this task?
What would be the ideal way of going about in this scenario?
NOTE: I want a cross platform solution which works on MacOSX and GNU/Linux.

Comment: what is the input you need? could it be solved with environment variable?

Comment: @RafaelBarros The `input` can be any string, from 'World' to 'Rafael'. So, I don't think this can be solved using environment variables. Moreover, this is just a prototype code.

Comment: If it is running via cron or schedule, it will not be running on your terminal, therefore, it cannot be interactive. You will not be prompted. Or am I missing something? If you just want to put a delay of 5 minutes, have you looked at the Linux "sleep" command or using python's "time.sleep"?

Comment: @RobertB Thanks for your response. If you are able to write it up as a more elaborate answer, I am willing to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your could try the python module pexpect (http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/doc/) -- the usage is something like :

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn(script/python file etc...)
child.expect('Here goes the prompt you would expect')
child.sendline('What you want to send to it')
```

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to have cron interact interactively on your server.

Delink your application:
Setup a db (like MySQL), have test.py run via cron every 5 mins to check if a new entry is made in the db: then, have a local application that saves user prompt information to your db.

Answer (score 0):

If it is running via cron or schedule, it will not be running on your terminal, it will run as a background process. Therefore, it cannot be interactive and you will not be prompted.

If you just want to put a delay of 5 minutes, have you looked at the Linux "sleep" command or using python's "time.sleep"? In this way you can keep a terminal open and just have the job run in intervals.

To keep it simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

def foo():
    a = input()
    print("Hello, {}".format(a))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        foo()
        time.sleep(300) # Sleeps 300 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a script and use that in the crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/project/test.py << EOF
some input here
EOF
```

Your crontab will look like

```
* *  * * *   /home/user/project/test.sh >>  /home/user/project/LOG 2>&1
```